# Java string.equals if statement not working

Tags: java, string

Here is my code. When I print the string cmd, it prints out "print" but yet, my if statemnet still will not run. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
   String url = "http://xboxfl.co/java/inc/command.txt";
  String cmd = Methods.getContents(url, "UTF-8");
  System.out.println(cmd);
  if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("print")){
      System.out.println("it works");
  }
}
```

Hopefully someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: If you change cmd to cmd="print" it works fine, what is Methods ? Could you provide the code for methods.getContents)

Comment: What is `Methods.getContents` ?  where's that?

Comment: what is the output of your code if you run the above src?

Comment: I assure you that Java works perfectly fine. Whatever is in `cmd` is *not* "print".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
if(cmd.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("print"))
{
    System.out.println("it works");
}
```

`trim()` deletes any trailing spaces around the word `print`, if any.

Comment: That seamed to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should trim it, it's possible you have space or new line charachter before or after your string.

Answer (score 1):

Use bellow to trim and avoid possible nulPointerException

```
if(cmd!=null && cmd.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("print"))
  {
   System.out.println("it works");
  }
```

Edited OR

```
if(cmd!=null && "print".equalsIgnoreCase(cmd.trim()))
  {
   System.out.println("it works");
  }
```

Comment: +1 Your previous version was simpler ;) `"print".equalsIgnoreCase(cmd.trim())`.

Comment: Hmm but have to check cmd is null because cmd.trim() can throw NPE

Answer (score 1):

String.equals DOES work.

The most common cause of "`String.equals` does not work" syndrome is that there is leading and/or trailing whitespace in one of the strings and not the other.  The problem is that it is easy to miss the whitespace characters in a diagnostic traceprint.  (I usually put quotes around string values in traceprints to make any whitespace more obvious.  A debugger will also show the actual characters if you look carefully.)

Another, much more uncommon cause is that one of the strings being compared contains characters that look like the corresponding character in the other string, but in fact are not.  For instance, the Unicode Greek and Cyrillic code pages includes characters that *look* like Latin letters, but are in fact different characters.  You can get similar problems with accented characters because Unicode supports two different ways of representing them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your cmd variable has any blank space?